# How to add custom sort by option filter in tool bar in magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-options, sorting, toolbar

I want to custom sort by option filter attribute add in tool bar section. Currently Magento 2 provide Position , Product Name , Price And Sorting option to low to high. But i need to change all sorting option Like Price High to Low , Price Low to High.

Answer (score 5):

I created these custom sort by options:

- price high - low --> (including all forms of discounts)
- price low - high --> (including all forms of discounts)
- name a-z
- name z-a
- newest
- oldest

**Magento 2.4+ (when ElasticSearch is used)**

Read full instructions below at 2.4- section but implement changes from this section if you use ElasticSearch (M2.4+)

Main difference when using ElasticSearch instead of MySql is that using a plugin to control `Toolbar.php` `setCollection` method doesn't seem to work (probably because of ElasticSearch).

But using `preference` in di.xml instead works:

`<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />`

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }

        $currentOrder = $this->getCurrentOrder();
        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'name_az') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'asc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'name_za') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'desc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price_asc') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price_desc') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'newest') { // created_at must have "used_for_sort_by = 1" in catalog_eav_attribute table
                $this->_collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'oldest') {
                $this->_collection->setOrder('created_at', 'asc');
            } else {
                $this->_collection->setOrder($currentOrder, $this->getCurrentDirection());
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Note the comment next to `newest` order - if you use newset/oldest sorting by `created_at` attribute you need to change the value of the field `used_for_sort_by` to `1` in `catalog_eav_attribute` table for this attribute.

Also in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config` make sure to put `unset($options['created_at']);` since the actual options used are newest/oldest.

Afterwards, just reindex and clear cache.

**Magento 2.4- (when Mysql search engine is used)**

by creating a plugin to bypass the default functionality of the product sorter which can be found here:

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

and

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Config

You start by creating your own `module` and registering it.

Then create:

> {Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Vendor_ModuleName::addCustomSortOptions" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Vendor_ModuleName::implementCustomSortOptions" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create

> {Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Plugin/Model/Config.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model;

class Config
{
    /**
     * Adding custom options and changing labels
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param [] $options
     * @return []
     */
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        //Remove default sorting options
        unset($options['position']);
        unset($options['name']);
        unset($options['price']);
    
        //Change label of default sorting options if needed
        //$options['position'] = __('Relevance');
    
        //New sorting options
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price High - Low');
        $options['price_asc'] = __('Price Low - High');
        $options['newest'] = __('Newest');
        $options['oldest'] = __('Oldest');
        $options['name_az'] = __('Product Name A - Z');
        $options['name_za'] = __('Product Name Z - A');
    
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Create

> {vendor}/{modulename}/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
        $result = $proceed($collection);
            
        if ($currentOrder) {
            switch ($currentOrder) {
            
            case 'newest':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.created_at DESC');
            break;
            
            case 'oldest':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.created_at ASC');

            break;
            
            case 'price_desc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price DESC');
            break;
            
            case 'price_asc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price ASC');
            break;
            
            case 'name_az':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.name ASC');
            break;
            
            case 'name_za':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.name DESC');
            break;
            
            default:        
                $this->_collection
                    ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
            break;
            
            }
        }
        //var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect()); You can use this to get a list of all the available sort fields
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed above steps replace code from {vendor}/{modulename} to our {vendor}/{modulename}. after creating attributes form backend. but it seems no luck.

Comment: @AnikeshShahi what do you mean "after creating attributes from backend"? This works for sure in Magento 2.2. I suggest you double check if you changed all {vendor} & {modulename} with your own. And make sure you did **setup:upgrade**, **setup:di:compile**, **clear static files** and **cache**.

Comment: I already checked, attributes shows in drop  down tool bar but not filtering as per selection.

Comment: @AnikeshShahi if you see the new options, but they don't work, you might have made a mistake in Toolbar.php or maybe you have conflicting modules (which both change the functionality of the toolbar). Maybe you could edit your question with your attempted solution and I could help you locate the mistake.

Comment: I want to sort the collection by custom price using default sort by price. Have you any solution? **@Lez**

Comment: @DhadukMitesh I suggest you create a separate question with more information on what you need, so someone (maybe me) can help you. I cannot help via comments like this...

Comment: @Lez I have created a module with the above coding and it appears to have added the options to the sort filter, however selecting the options doesn't reload the page or apply the filter? Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: @heady12 seems like you might have some JS error on the page. You could try running setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, flushing static content and flushing cache. Also i tested this code only on Mage 2.2.2 and 2.2.3. So it might be a compatibility issue for previous Mage versions. Cant suggest anything else other than this...good luck!

Comment: not working in Magento 2.3.2 options are shown in dropdown but no products are returned when an option is selected.

Comment: @paj can't say about 2.3.2, but I have a site with 2.3.0 on which it's working. I doubt 2.3.2 brought changes that would break this functionality so I would suggest double checking that you have all the files and that no other modules are affecting the sorting functionality.

Comment: can we implement most viewed in to it please reply me if yes then how??

Comment: @Pramod that is not possible by default in Magento 2, because products don't have "view counters". It would require a separate complex module to accomplish something like this.

Comment: but there is a functinality in admin dashboard that shows most viewed product cant we use it

Comment: You are right, but I don't think this data is available in the collection for sorting. Check the last lines of `Toolbar.php` in my answer: you can get all available data for sorting on the screen with `var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect());` So you can check if there is something like "product views" in there. I believe that for sorting you need a product attribute, while product views are not an attribute, but a statistical (report) data.

Comment: Hello @Lez, your solution is working fine for price sorting but not for the name. I checked and found that name is not present in collection so need to fetch name from other tables using join I guess. Could you please help me with this? I'm using Magento 2.3.4, Thanks.

Comment: @vartikasharma I'm using this solution on a 2.3.5 shop and it works. Not sure why it's not working on yours. I suggest you check which data you get with `var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect());` before `return $result`. It might show you different fields so you can adjust Toolbar.php accordingly.

Comment: @lez I tried that but not getting product name in the collection

Comment: @vartikasharma Most probably some extension is modifying the collection. Maybe you could search your `/app/code/` folder for `toolbar.php`, or just `toolbar` and see if any extension is modifying the query/collection. Then you can disable it or try to modify it to suit your needs. Also if you tried different solutions for the custom toolbar, you probably need to disable your other attempts, because they probably modify the same thing and you might get unexpected results (like what you are seeing now).

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` and `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config`.

**etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
       <plugin name="override-config" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Plugin\Config" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**{vendor}{module}\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php**

```
namespace {Vendor}\{module}\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar {
  public function setCollection($collection) {
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    $limit = (int) $this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            case 'created_at':
                if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection
                            ->getSelect()
                            ->order('e.created_at DESC');
                } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection
                            ->getSelect()
                            ->order('e.created_at ASC');
                }
                break;
            case 'in_stock':
                $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->joinLeft(
                                ['admin' => $collection->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_item')], 'e.entity_id = admin.product_id')->where('admin.is_in_stock = 1');
                break;
            case 'out_stock':
                $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->joinLeft(
                                ['admin' => $collection->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_item')], 'e.entity_id = admin.product_id')->where('admin.is_in_stock = 0');
                break;
            default:
                $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
                break;
        }
    }
    return $this;
  }
}
```

**{Vendor}{Module}\Model\Plugin\Config.php**

```
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Plugin;
class Config {

   public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options
   ) {

    $options['created_at'] = __('Newest');
    $options['in_stock'] = __('In Stock');
    $options['out_stock'] = __('Out of Stock');
    return $options;
   }
}
```

Comment: Small remark. You need join cataloginventory_stock_status not cataloginventory_stock_item table

Comment: Have you any solution for it? i have for `cataloginventory_stock_item`. and its working fine

Comment: I want to sort the collection by custom price using default sort by price. Have you any solution? **@Lez**

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using following code. 
**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Sortby',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Sortby" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Anshu\Sortby\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config" type="Anshu\Sortby\Model\Config" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/Model/Config.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Sortby\Model;

class Config extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
{

    /**
     * Retrieve Attributes Used for Sort by as array
     * key = code, value = name
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = ['position' => __('Most Popular')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        $options['position'] = __('Most Popular');
        $options['price'] =  __('Price: Low to High');
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price: High to Low');
        return $options;
    }

}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/Block/Catalog/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Sortby\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ToolbarModel;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    /**
     * Set collection to pager
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
                case 'price':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), 'ASC');
                    break;

                case 'price_desc':
                    $this->_collection
                            ->getSelect()
                            ->order('price_index.price DESC');

                default:
                    //$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), 'DESC');
                break;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: how  do you implement most  most viewed sorting option please reply ??

Comment: @Pramod Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194537/product-list-page-sort-by-most-view-in-magento-2-1

Comment: i cant find your ans if you really knows way you can post your and here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302016/magento2-display-most-viewed-sorting-option