# Magento 2 custom sort option with elastic search

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

I have to implement below custom sort options

```
– Order: A to Z
– Order: Z to A
– Price: Low to High
– Price: High to Low
```

I have tried with the example given in [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283582/custom-sort-by-is-not-working-with-elastic-search-in-magento-2-3). 
This is not working with elastic search. I am getting a message

> We can't find products matching the selection.

Please help me if anyone has implemented this.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Didn't get the exact solution but ended with adding some custom logic in toolbar.js to handle sorting.

Answer (score -1):

Custom Sort with ElasticSearch in Magento issue can be fixed by following these simple steps:

- Navigate to **Stores**->**Attributes**->**Product** in Admin.
- **Add New Attribute**.
- In **Properties**->**Attribute Properties**:

  - Add **Default Label** (Eg: Price: Low to High)
  - Select the **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** (Eg: Price) (In other cases Text Field is enough).
- In **Properties**->**Advanced Attribute Properties**:

  - Add **Attribute Code** (Eg: price_asc).
- In **Storefront Properties**->**Storefront Properties**:

  - Select **User for Sorting in Product Listing** to **Yes**

Once done with the above steps run the following commands,

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: You've just added a product attribute as an answer to creating a custom product sort order that works with Elastic Search...!? :/