# Magento2 display most viewed sorting option

Tags: magento2.3.3

hi am trying to display most viewed as a sorting option like this but its not working whereas price high-low and low-high is working

here is my full code:-

**config.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Module\Plugin\Model;

class Config
{
    /**
     * Adding custom options and changing labels
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param [] $options
     * @return []
     */
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        //Remove default sorting options
        unset($options['position']);
        unset($options['name']);
        unset($options['price']);

        //Change label of default sorting options if needed
        //$options['position'] = __('Relevance');

        //New sorting options
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price High - Low');
        $options['price_asc'] = __('Price Low - High');
        $options['newest'] = __('Newest');
        $options['most_viewed'] = __('Most Viewed');
        // $options['name_az'] = __('Product Name A - Z');
        // $options['name_za'] = __('Product Name Z - A');

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**Toolbar.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            switch ($currentOrder) {

            case 'newest':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('e.created_at DESC');
            break;

            // // case 'oldest':
            // //     $this->_collection
            // //         ->getSelect()
            // //         ->order('e.created_at ASC');

            // break;

            case 'price_desc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price DESC');
            break;

            case 'price_asc':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('price_index.min_price ASC');
            break;

            case 'most_viewed':
                $this->_collection
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->order('report_event_index');
            break;

            default:        
                $this->_collection
                    ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
            break;

            }
        }
        // var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect()); 
        // You can use this to get a list of all the available sort fields
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262124/59677

Comment: i have tried that bu its not working